# парсинг текста из html через python

Tags: html, python, парсер

```
<a class="drug__link drug__link--article" href="//www.rlsnet.ru/fg_index_id_642.htm">Средства для лечения <span class="sokr" title="вирус иммунодефицита человека">ВИЧ</span>-инфекции в комбинациях</a>
```

Требуется достать весь текст, чтобы получить

> Средства для лечения ВИЧ-инфекции в комбинациях

уже всю голову сломал, по отдельности могу достать, а чтоб цельная фраза получилась не выходит. Нужно решение для текстов с большим количеством `<span>` тегов.

Comment: Удалить все что между < и >?

Comment: можно и так сказать, что-то не подумал. регуляркой можно ведь?

Comment: Можно, но не нужно, делается через поиск и замену, например.

Comment: А пример, будьте добры?

Comment: startPos = str.find("start")
endPos = str.find("end")
str = str.replace(str[startPos:endPos], "")

Comment: так это то понятно, а все как почистить? цикл до тех пор пока теги не кончатся? :)

Comment: Разумеется, цикл пока что-то найдено

Comment: у меня там есть тексты с десятками тегов, если не сотнями. такой вариант увы не подходит

Comment: Напишите регулярку и тогда вы узнаете, что такое "не подходит". Конечный автомат еще можно зопилить, но вам тоже не понравится :-D

Comment: В lxml есть `text_content()`

Comment: Используйте *правильные* средства для этого. `from lxml import etree` и далее по тексту. Вот я парсил вывод негоего сайта для примера: https://pastebin.com/htRjPBb0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

s = '<a class="drug__link drug__link--article" href="//www.rlsnet.ru/fg_index_id_642.htm">Средства для лечения <span class="sokr" title="вирус иммунодефицита человека">ВИЧ</span>-инфекции в комбинациях</a>'
soup = bs(s, "lxml")
out_string = ''.join([x.text for x in soup.findAll('a')])
print(out_string)

#### Средства для лечения ВИЧ-инфекции в комбинациях
```

Answer (score 0):

регулярка все же тащит, не знаю почему сразу не догадался

```html
sometext = u'<a class="drug__link drug__link--article" href="//www.rlsnet.ru/fg_index_id_642.htm">\u0421\u0440\u0435\u0434\u0441\u0442\u0432\u0430 \u0434\u043b\u044f \u043b\u0435\u0447\u0435\u043d\u0438\u044f <span class="sokr" title="\u0432\u0438\u0440\u0443\u0441 \u0438\u043c\u043c\u0443\u043d\u043e\u0434\u0435\u0444\u0438\u0446\u0438\u0442\u0430 \u0447\u0435\u043b\u043e\u0432\u0435\u043a\u0430">\u0412\u0418\u0427</span>-\u0438\u043d\u0444\u0435\u043a\u0446\u0438\u0438 \u0432 \u043a\u043e\u043c\u0431\u0438\u043d\u0430\u0446\u0438\u044f\u0445</a>'
p = re.compile(r'<.*?>')
print p.sub('', sometext)
```

Comment: Не надо парсить HTML регулярками

Comment: -1 к ответу. Ужас.